# Ir a pantalla principal desde cualquier pantalla en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation

Tengo un proyecto en Android studio con varios activity, en el cual quiero que al momento en el que presione el botón back de la barra de navegación regrese a la pantalla principal de mi proyecto.

De antemano gracias

Comment: Hola @ArmandoEscobedo, tu pregunta no se adecua a las normas del sitio. Por favor, lee el [tour] y [ask] para que puedas ver como funciona el sitio y puedas editar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida. Si la dejas así corres el riesgo de que sea cerrada.

Comment: Es importante revises los documentos que indica Pablo, en realidad falta más información, no comentas como esta estructurado tu proyecto, las actividades que comentas están en el mismo nivel o pueden estar en una pila?

Answer (score 0):

Si estás abriendo actividades desde otras actividades (además de la `MainActivity`) entonces lo que tienes que hacer es terminar esas actividades con [`finish()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finish()) justo despues de la llamada a `startActivity`.

De esa manera toda actividad que ya no se vea estará muerta (a excepción de la MainActivity).

Comment: Si son varías activities en pila con esto no podría regresar a la principal.

Comment: Porque no regresaría?

Comment: Si regresaría a la "anterior" pero si después de la principal se abrieron dos más, entonces solo regresaría a la anterior y no a la "principal".

Comment: Ah, pero esas dos anteriores ya estarían finalizadas, fuera del stack.

Comment: Eso no lo sabemos ya que no lo especifica el OP, no hay que contestar preguntas que no especifiquen correctamente lo especificado en [ask]

Comment: Corrigiendo tu segundo comentario: Sí regresaría a la principal porque es la unica que quedaría en el stak, la 'anterior' estaría muerta. Si el OP mata la principal, es otro tema.

Answer (score 0):

Desde mi absoluta novatez, imagino que se podría sobreescribiría el método onBackPressed y ahí hacer un intent a la Activity que se quiera:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  //Aquí tu Intent...
}
```

Comment: ¿Si la Activity ya esta cargada que sucedería al realizar un Intent a la misma Activity?

Answer (score 0):

Hola deberías probar sobre escribiendo el método @back con un intento que revise si existe ya en la pila el activity deseada, de este modo evitarias estar creando instancias inecesarias, las banderas que puedes usar son Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP que limpiaria la pila despues de hacer el intent y Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP que revisa si existe la actividad en la pila

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {    
    Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HomeActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Las respuestas que tienen código solamente se las considera de baja calidad, por favor revisa [answer]

Comment: Gracias la he modificado.